# Remove all text before (and excluding) match

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, regex, regexextract

Hi I have a cell with data such as:

```
Dropped pin
Near Hughanden Village Hall, Pome Ln, Hughanden, Low Slokey, HT11 3AT
https://goo.gl/maps/dVtKw423RBA9fkGs7
```

I would like to use `REGEXREPLACE` (or one of the other REGEX functions) to remove the text before the URL. As you can see newlines are present which has been stumping me a bit.

To further complicate matters the data in the cell is user submitted with no validation and may not have a URL at all; simply a description or some GPS coordinates. In either of those situations, I would like the cell contents to remain unchanged.

Am I asking too much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "http.*")
```

[image: 0]

### ______________________________________________________

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(D2:D, 
 "(\d+.\d+,.*)|(http.*)|\((.*)\)"))),,999^99))))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks that helps a lot. I don't think I'd really taken much notice of that function!
However this doesn't help with the second part of the question - what if the data in the cell is eg (51.6647524, -0.7363616)

Comment: Here's a partial copy i can share https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SeNln8M74lQnxdJF-v9MjZQTq7XYqq-LSsNktdRW7uA/edit?usp=sharing - I've now enabled editing of it

Comment: @fearoffours answer updated

Comment: great. What about row 13?

Comment: @fearoffours row 13 does not have url nor coords